# ASP.NET to convert binary data to string

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm trying to develop API that returns a profile of employees including their pictures, the images are stored in SQL database as image data type

```
    TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)typeConverter.ConvertFrom(Emp.img);

    //3
    var Fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images") + @"\I" + id.ToString() + ".png", FileMode.Create);
    bmp.Save(Fs, ImageFormat.Png);
    bmp.Dispose();


    //4
    Image img = Image.FromStream(Fs);
    Fs.Close();
    Fs.Dispose();


    //5
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);


    //6
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
    ms.Close();
    ms.Dispose();

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return response;
}
```

I want to use this API in Android Studio where I have to convert the image data type to string or any other applicable data time with Volley.

Comment: if someone wants any further information, let me know, thanks

Comment: Just convert the binary to base64 if you need it as string. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a base64 representation of the image:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"your\path\to\image.png");
string imageAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

Then send it back to the Android Studio client and do the following:

```
byte[] imageAsStringInAndroidStudio = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Just check if you have to strip the "data:image/jpg;base64" from the data before parsing it into Android Studio.